# Calculating averages C++

Tags: c++

I am required to show two decimal places in my average. Right now, it rounds to the nearest number, and shows zeros when there is a different number in the calculated amount for the tenths and hundredths. Probably something very simple I am overlooking. I thought that declaring the type as double would allow this to show the correct calculation.

```
double CalculateAverageScore(int score[],int numPlayers, double averageScore)
{
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
    {
        total += score[i];
    }
    averageScore = total / numPlayers;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "\nAverage Score: " << averageScore << endl;
    return averageScore;
}
```

Comment: Why is `double averageScore` an argument and no locale variable?

Comment: Remove the parameter `double averageScore` since you return the value and don't change the argument.

Comment: Because I have to use it in another function that displays the names and scores of the players that are below average. It is declared in the function, so I don't need to make it a local variable. If I am wrong, please let me know, I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should work as is according to your example.

```
double total = 0;
// ...
averageScore = total / numPlayers; // Result of division is of type double.
```

Here you are dividing a `double` by an `int` and the result should be a `double`. Thus no cast is needed.

Some other problems though:

- You have declared the parameter `score` as `int*` which allows a client to pass a null-value (and you don't check for this).
- You have declared the parameter `numPlayers` as `int` which is bad practice, instead declare as `std::size_t`.
- `averageScore` is declared as a parameter but the argument is never used. Instead declare it as a local variable.
- You have lacking const-correctness, i.e. pass parameters as `const` when you do not intend to modify.

Consider passing `score` as a reference to an `int[N]` using a template parameter instead. Then you will not have to pass the array length as a second parameter. E.g.:

```
template <const std::size_t N>
double average(const int (&score)[N]) {
    return static_cast<double>(std::accumulate(std::begin(score), std::end(score), 0)) / N;
}
```

And use as:

```
int score[5] = { 2, 2, 3, 4, 5};
std::cout << std::fixed << std::showpoint << std::setprecision(2);
std::cout << average(score) << std::endl; // Outputs 3.20
```

Alternatively use a container from the Standard Library instead of a built in array for `score`, e.g. [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: 1. That is what I thought. I double checked the book, and it makes sense that the cast fixes it. The example says that without the cast, 1/2 is 0 because even as a double, there is no decimal. the cast makes it 1.0/2 which equals .5.                                 2.

Comment: @Zach707 Passing a `double` and an `int` to binary operator for division will promote the `int` to a `double` and perform floating point division. Thus `1.0 / 2` becomes `1.0 / 2.0` and the result is `0.5`.

Comment: @Zach707 I've compiled your function untouched on GCC 4.8.2 and it will output the average with two decimals.

Comment: 2. I don't know what std::size_t is yet, still learning and only allowed to use what I've been taught for each assignment. 3. I have tried to delete this from the prototype and header, but the program goes crazy. I do use it in the next function which displays the players and scores below average. Any advice is greatly appreciated............. My output is now exactly like the sample for the lesson, but I am still wanting to learn simple and good practices to better myself.

Comment: I am using visual c++ as required by school.

Comment: @Zach707 A (signed) `int` ranges from -2147483648 through 2147483647 on most systems. This is not practical for use as an array index as the negative part is useless and the array might be bigger than what can be indexed by the positive part. The type `std::size_t` is guaranteed to be big enough to fit an index to any array on a system.

Comment: @Zach707 Make sure to remove the unnecessary parameter in both the declaration and the definition of the function, and also at the call site.

Answer (score 5):

```
averageScore = total / numPlayers;
                    ^^^
          integer division
```

In order to preserve double precision:

```
averageScore = static_cast< double>( total) / numPlayers;
                  ^^^
               explicit cast
```

However in case you are dividing a `double` by an `int` result should be already a `double` and no cast is needed.

---

And since you explained you are interested to hear about best practices now, being on your stage in programming curve - you should really change function to

```
double CalculateAverageScore(int score[],int numPlayers)
{
    //...
    double averageScore = total / numPlayers;
    return averageScore;
}
```

as you previously have taken `averageScore` as argument but haven't use it's initial value:

```
double CalculateAverageScore(int score[],int numPlayers, double averageScore)
{
    double total = 0.0;
    //...
    averageScore = total / numPlayers;
                 ^
           forget initial value, so it was useless
           == no need to pass averageScore as argument
    //....
}
```

Comment: As explicitly asked for [tag:c++] I'd recommend `double(total)`

Comment: It would be somewhat better to use a C++ `static_cast` in a C++ program. Also, inexperienced programmers might think that the `(double)` cast applies to the quotient instead of the dividend.

Comment: Yes, cool.                                                         I found averageScore = static_cast<double>(total)/numPLayers      in the book, but your way is more simple. Will remember it.

Comment: @user100748 The big disadvantage of C-style casts is that they can be used to perform just about any type cast or type conversion that you may or may not want (such as removing `const` or casting an integral number to a pointer). It is better to be explicit about the intended cast, so that your compiler can warn you if you do something unintended.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Felix, that makes sense. I am new to this, so good habits will be best picked up now.